# How to get other columns in this query

Tags: sql

I am using a `group by` clause in my query. I want to get other columns not specified in the group by parameters

```
SELECT un.user, un.role 
FROM [Unique] un 
group by user, role
```

In the query about [Unique] has 7 columns altogether. How do I get the other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most databases (MySQL and SQLite are the exceptions I know of), you cannot include a column in a GROUP BY SELECT unless:

1. The column is included in the GROUP BY clause.
2. The column is *aggregated* in one of the supported aggregate functions.

In MySQL and SQLite, the rows inside the aggregate groups from which the extra values get taken are undefined.

If you want extra columns in any other engine, you can wrap the column names in MAX():

```
 SELECT un.user, un.role, MAX(un.city), MAX(un.bday)
 FROM [Unique] un 
 GROUP BY user, role
```

In this case, the values for the extra columns are likely to come from *different* rows in the input record set.  If this is important (sometimes it isn't since the extra columns come from the one side of a one-to-many JOIN), you can't use this technique.

Just to be clear: If you use GROUP BY in a SELECT, then each row you get back is constructed out of *groups* of multiple rows in the table you're SELECTing against.  If you include columns that are not part of the GROUP BY clause, you're not giving the engine any instructions on *which* row from the table you want that value read from.  Most engines, therefore, do not allow you to run this kind of SQL.  MySQL does, with undefined results but I personally consider it bad practice to do this.

Comment: perfect, I understand why I must use MAX now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose on what basis you want the other columns. If multiple entries exist for the same user / role, do you want the first / last / random? You have to make choices on the other columns, by aggregating them or choosing to include them in the group by statement.

Some RDBMS do provide a default behaviour for performing this, but since the question is just marked SQL, we do not know if it applies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just specifying them?

```
SELECT un.user, un.role, un.col3, un.col4
FROM [Unique] un 
group by user, role
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Order By to get extra column. or you end up specifying every column in your group by.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to self-join the Unique or use the `SELECT` with `GROUP BY` as sub-query.